# How to convert & rotate raw NV21 array image (android.media.Image) from front cam portrait mode in onImageAvailable (android Camera2)?

Tags: android, rotation, android-camera2, portrait, front-camera

**Note: All info in my post only goes for Samsung Galaxy S7 device. I do not know how emulators and other devices behave.**

In onImageAvailable I convert continuously each image to a NV21 byte array and forward it to an API expecting raw NV21 format.

This is how I initialize the image reader and receive the images:

```
private void openCamera() {
    ...
    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(WIDTH, HEIGHT,
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1); // only 1 for best performance
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
    mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
    ...
}

private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        if (image != null) {
            byte[] data = convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES(image); // this image is turned 90 deg using front cam in portrait mode
            byte[] data_rotated = rotateNV21_working(data, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 270);
            ForwardToAPI(data_rotated); // image data is being forwarded to api and received later on
            image.close();
        }
    }
};
```

The function converting the image to raw NV21 ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39024263/2385845)), working fine, the image is (due to android?) turned by 90 degrees when using front cam in portrait mode:
(I modified it, slightly according to comments of Alex Cohn)

```
private byte[] convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES(Image imgYUV420) {

    byte[] rez;

    ByteBuffer buffer0 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer2 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    // actually here should be something like each second byte
    // however I simply get the last byte of buffer 2 and the entire buffer 1
    int buffer0_size = buffer0.remaining();
    int buffer1_size = buffer1.remaining(); // / 2 + 1;
    int buffer2_size = 1;//buffer2.remaining(); // / 2 + 1;

    byte[] buffer0_byte = new byte[buffer0_size];
    byte[] buffer1_byte = new byte[buffer1_size];
    byte[] buffer2_byte = new byte[buffer2_size];

    buffer0.get(buffer0_byte, 0, buffer0_size);
    buffer1.get(buffer1_byte, 0, buffer1_size);
    buffer2.get(buffer2_byte, buffer2_size-1, buffer2_size);


    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        // swap 1 and 2 as blue and red colors are swapped
        outputStream.write(buffer0_byte);
        outputStream.write(buffer2_byte);
        outputStream.write(buffer1_byte);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    rez = outputStream.toByteArray();

    return rez;
}
```

Hence "data" needs to be rotated. Using this function ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207392/2385845)), I get a weird *3-times interlaced picture* error:

```
public static byte[] rotateNV21(byte[] input, int width, int height, int rotation) {
    byte[] output = new byte[input.length];
    boolean swap = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270);
    // **EDIT:** in portrait mode & front cam this needs to be set to true:
    boolean yflip = true;// (rotation == 90 || rotation == 180);
    boolean xflip = (rotation == 270 || rotation == 180);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int xo = x, yo = y;
            int w = width, h = height;
            int xi = xo, yi = yo;
            if (swap) {
                xi = w * yo / h;
                yi = h * xo / w;
            }
            if (yflip) {
                yi = h - yi - 1;
            }
            if (xflip) {
                xi = w - xi - 1;
            }
            output[w * yo + xo] = input[w * yi + xi];
            int fs = w * h;
            int qs = (fs >> 2);
            xi = (xi >> 1);
            yi = (yi >> 1);
            xo = (xo >> 1);
            yo = (yo >> 1);
            w = (w >> 1);
            h = (h >> 1);
            // adjust for interleave here
            int ui = fs + (w * yi + xi) * 2;
            int uo = fs + (w * yo + xo) * 2;
            // and here
            int vi = ui + 1;
            int vo = uo + 1;
            output[uo] = input[ui];
            output[vo] = input[vi];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Resulting into this picture:

[image: bad result]

**Note: it is still the same cup, however you see it 3-4 times.**

Using another suggested rotate function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425229/2385845) gives the proper result:

```
public static byte[] rotateNV21_working(final byte[] yuv,
                                final int width,
                                final int height,
                                final int rotation)
{
  if (rotation == 0) return yuv;
  if (rotation % 90 != 0 || rotation < 0 || rotation > 270) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("0 <= rotation < 360, rotation % 90 == 0");
  }

  final byte[]  output    = new byte[yuv.length];
  final int     frameSize = width * height;
  final boolean swap      = rotation % 180 != 0;
  final boolean xflip     = rotation % 270 != 0;
  final boolean yflip     = rotation >= 180;

  for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      final int yIn = j * width + i;
      final int uIn = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width + (i & ~1);
      final int vIn = uIn       + 1;

      final int wOut     = swap  ? height              : width;
      final int hOut     = swap  ? width               : height;
      final int iSwapped = swap  ? j                   : i;
      final int jSwapped = swap  ? i                   : j;
      final int iOut     = xflip ? wOut - iSwapped - 1 : iSwapped;
      final int jOut     = yflip ? hOut - jSwapped - 1 : jSwapped;

      final int yOut = jOut * wOut + iOut;
      final int uOut = frameSize + (jOut >> 1) * wOut + (iOut & ~1);
      final int vOut = uOut + 1;

      output[yOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[yIn]);
      output[uOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[uIn]);
      output[vOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[vIn]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

The result is fine now:

[image: fine result]

The top image shows the direct stream using a texture view's surface and adding it to the captureRequestBuilder. The bottom image shows the raw image data after rotating.

The questions are:

- Does this hack in "convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES" work on any
  device/emulator?
- Why does rotateNV21 not work, while rotateNV21_working works fine.

*Edit: The mirror issue is fixed, see code comment. The squeeze issue is fixed, it was caused by the API it gets forwarded.
The actual open issue is a proper not too expensive function, converting and rotating an image into raw NV21 working on any device.*

Comment: On the face of it, the rotated image should have the cup lying on its side, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlexCohn: The cup shouldn't be "squeezed" as it is right now on the bottom picture. If I display "data" I have the exact same picture as the one on top but 90 deg turned. Hence I am using "rotateNV21" however with the issue that the picture is squeezed, i.e. the width is too high and the height too low. This is what I need to fix.

Comment: You mean, the top image in your screenshot is rotated 90°?

Comment: @AlexCohn: See my edited post (the picture). Android's front camera in portrait mode has the issue, that raw frames (i.e. NV21 byte array) are rotated by 90 deg (picture in the middle). Hence I use the function "rotateNV21". This however changes the width and height of the picture, giving a bad result (bottom picture). It should look like the top picture. So rotateNV21 needs to be adjust, not to swap width and height. My question is how to do that.

Comment: The code for rotation looks correct (while not optimal). Just to be on the safe side, please verify that the length of output of `rotateNV21()` is equal to `width*height*3/2`. I suspect that the problem is with the function you use to convert NV21 to bitmap for display.

Comment: @AlexCohn: It's not. 
Both the result of "convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES" and "rotateNV21" have a length of 614398. Width = 640, height = 480.
640*480*3/2 = 460.800 - so there is definitely an issue.
However: Android displays the arrays just fine (see picture).
ImageReader is initialized with ImageFormat.YUV_420_888.

Comment: On a Nexus 5 device I get same buffer sizes. Actually, here plane[2], is same as plane[1], except 1-byte offset. The result is that if you read every second byte in plane[1], you get U, exactly as explained in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888; and if you read every second byte in plane[2], you get V. But if you simply concatenate plane[0] and plane[1], you get an NV21 image (without the last U pixel). The bottom line, your `convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES()` produces correct image only by lucky chance.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I think the reason it still showed the proper picture was due to the byte array simple being cut by the API. So the image had 614398 (buffer0+buffer2+buffer1), the API cut it down to 460800 so the image was built by buffer0+buffer2+first px of buffer1.
So whats the correct way to handle it? Read every 2nd byte in plane[1] and plane[2]? or read plane[2] + last byte of plane[1] (if I read plane[1] first, blue and red is swapped)-
Anyways: I corrected it now, still with the same result. The rotated image is still "squeezed".

Comment: Note: The "squeeze" issue is fixed, it was caused by the API I forwarded the data to. Now (thanks to your input) the real question has arisen, how to convert Image to NV21 (and then rotate it) correctly, so it works on all devices and not just mine.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a fair use of the SO resource. This site was designed to ask specific questions, while yours is a 'moving target'.

Comment: It is as my original question had 2 issues, one (squeezed image) which was caused by a sheer mistake of me and one which is still up & which you addressed. As I found out and fixed the mistake, the "real" question is still up and you already gave input. I could as well close this question and open a new one, but the content would be the same. Any comment/answer you gave was correct regarding the question asked right now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to convert the **Image** to **NV21** byte[]. This will work when the **imgYUV420** U and V planes have pixelStride=1 (as on emulator) or pixelStride=2 (as on Nexus):

```
private byte[] convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES(Image imgYUV420) {

    assert(imgYUV420.getFormat() == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
    Log.d(TAG, "image: " + imgYUV420.getWidth() + "x" + imgYUV420.getHeight() + " " + imgYUV420.getFormat());
    Log.d(TAG, "planes: " + imgYUV420.getPlanes().length);
    for (int nplane = 0; nplane < imgYUV420.getPlanes().length; nplane++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "plane[" + nplane + "]: length " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getBuffer().remaining() + ", strides: " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getPixelStride() + " " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getRowStride());
    }

    byte[] rez = new byte[imgYUV420.getWidth() * imgYUV420.getHeight() * 3 / 2];
    ByteBuffer buffer0 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer2 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int n = 0;
    assert(imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getPixelStride() == 1);
    for (int row = 0; row < imgYUV420.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < imgYUV420.getWidth(); col++) {
            rez[n++] = buffer0.get();
        }
    }
    assert(imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getPixelStride() == imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride());
    int stride = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride();
    for (int row = 0; row < imgYUV420.getHeight(); row += 2) {
        for (int col = 0; col < imgYUV420.getWidth(); col += 2) {
            rez[n++] = buffer1.get();
            rez[n++] = buffer2.get();
            for (int skip = 1; skip < stride; skip++) {
                if (buffer1.remaining() > 0) {
                    buffer1.get();
                }
                if (buffer2.remaining() > 0) {
                    buffer2.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.w(TAG, "total: " + rez.length);
    return rez;
}
```

*optimized Java code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740776/192373)*.

As you can see, it is very easy to change this code to produce a rotated image *in a single step*:

```
private byte[] rotateYUV420ToNV21(Image imgYUV420) {

    Log.d(TAG, "image: " + imgYUV420.getWidth() + "x" + imgYUV420.getHeight() + " " + imgYUV420.getFormat());
    Log.d(TAG, "planes: " + imgYUV420.getPlanes().length);
    for (int nplane = 0; nplane < imgYUV420.getPlanes().length; nplane++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "plane[" + nplane + "]: length " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getBuffer().remaining() + ", strides: " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getPixelStride() + " " + imgYUV420.getPlanes()[nplane].getRowStride());
    }

    byte[] rez = new byte[imgYUV420.getWidth() * imgYUV420.getHeight() * 3 / 2];
    ByteBuffer buffer0 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer1 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer buffer2 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int width = imgYUV420.getHeight();
    assert(imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getPixelStride() == 1);
    for (int row = imgYUV420.getHeight()-1; row >=0; row--) {
        for (int col = 0; col < imgYUV420.getWidth(); col++) {
            rez[col*width+row] = buffer0.get();
        }
    }
    int uv_offset = imgYUV420.getWidth()*imgYUV420.getHeight();
    assert(imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getPixelStride() == imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride());
    int stride = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride();
    for (int row = imgYUV420.getHeight() - 2; row >= 0; row -= 2) {
        for (int col = 0; col < imgYUV420.getWidth(); col += 2) {
            rez[uv_offset+col/2*width+row] = buffer1.get();
            rez[uv_offset+col/2*width+row+1] = buffer2.get();
            for (int skip = 1; skip < stride; skip++) {
                if (buffer1.remaining() > 0) {
                    buffer1.get();
                }
                if (buffer2.remaining() > 0) {
                    buffer2.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.w(TAG, "total rotated: " + rez.length);
    return rez;
}
```

I sincerely recommend the site http://rawpixels.net/ to see the actual structure of your raw images.

Comment: Is there any difference between reading each second byte (if stride = 1) or my edited function (see original post convertYUV420ToNV21_ALL_PLANES). I simply grab buffer1 completely and only the last byte of buffer2. (I get back to the rotation in a bit, thanks a bunch!)

Comment: The [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888) does not guarantee that **U** and **V** will be interlaced, and it does not guarantee the opposite. The only trusted fact is that you must skip `getPixelStride()` bytes between pixels.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the only appropriate in terms of functionality on all devices. However on my device (Galaxy S7) I (again) have to swap buffer1 and buffer2 to avoid mixed red/blue colors and the rotation is clockwise instead of counter-. The biggest issue is the performance. Using this function almost completely freezes the application, I have frame updates probably each 5 seconds while before I had probably 5-10 fps. I modified the question accordingly, please check my comment in the top post.

Comment: My fault: I produced NV12 instead of NV21. Regarding rotation, this depends on `CameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION)`.

Comment: You can achieve better performance by reading all buffers in byte arrays: the tradeoff is memory. But for real boost, you can use renderscript.

Answer (score 1):

With `OpenCV` and Android Camera API 2 this task is very fast and you don't need `YUV420toNV21` Java conversion, and with `OpenCV` this convertion is **4x more fast**:

**Java side**:

```
//Starts a builtin camera with api camera 2
public void startCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) AppData.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String pickedCamera = getCamera(manager);
        manager.openCamera(pickedCamera, cameraStateCallback, null);
        // set image format on YUV
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth,mHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 4);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "imageReader created");
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}


//Listens for frames and send them to  be processed
protected ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = null;
        try {

            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] frameData = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(frameData);
            // Native process (see below)
            processAndRotateFrame(frameData);
            image.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "imageReader exception: "+e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Native side (NDK or Cmake):**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  com_android_mvf_Utils_ProccessAndRotateFrame
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray frame, jint rotation) {
    // load data from JAVA side
    jbyte *pFrameData = env->GetByteArrayElements(frame, 0);
    // convert array to Mat, for example GRAY or COLOR
    Mat mGray(height, width, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, (unsigned char *)pFrameData);
    // rotate image
    rotateMat(mGray, rotation);
    int objects = your_function(env, mGray);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(frame, pFrameData, 0);
    return objects;
}

void rotateMat(cv::Mat &matImage, int rotFlag) {
    if (rotFlag != 0 && rotFlag != 360) {
        if (rotFlag == 90) {
            cv::transpose(matImage, matImage);
            cv::flip(matImage, matImage, 1);
        } else if (rotFlag == 270 || rotFlag == -90) {
            cv::transpose(matImage, matImage);
            cv::flip(matImage, matImage, 0);
        } else if (rotFlag == 180) {
            cv::flip(matImage, matImage, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you copy from ByteBuffer to array you waste time. You don't show how to rotate NV21 colour info. You assume that OpenCV is available. Except from that, your answer is correct: it's faster to do conversion&rotation in C++.